# Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet

Tags: wireless

i have installed Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet , but when i restart my pc , its gone and i need to install it again ? why it is gone every restart like deletes from the system ?

Comment: What did you install and how? What is your OS?